# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Message

Tags: java, jboss, cloud, classnotfoundexception, mime

I have a JBoss application on google cloud VM which has an API to upload a zip files. I am getting below error while making call to API. Note this happens only with JBoss on google Cloud but not with non-cloud application :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Message from [Module "org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider:main" from local module loader @33e5ccce (finder: local module finder @5a42bbf4 (roots: /usr/share/jbossas/modules,/usr/share/jbossas/modules/system/layers/base))]
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataReader.readFrom(MultipartFormDataReader.java:54)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataReader.readFrom(MultipartFormDataReader.java:23)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:106)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:123)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:109)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:168)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:160)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:583)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:565)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:130)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847).
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ApoloRadomer : I am trying to upload a zip file through the API

Answer (score 0):

CLASSPATH on the Google Cloud is not set up properly. You will need to update it to make sure it includes the referenced class `org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Message`.